# Exporting a Grid over multiple pages

Tags: export, grid-layouts, pagelayout

I have a large output currently in grids which I need to export to `.pdf`, with the grid centered on the page, as well as break over multiple pages. Ideally I am looking to have 3 or 4 rows on each page.

Essence of the code is:

```
Grid[Partition[Table[i, {i, 0, 50}], 4], Spacings -> {3, 2}, Frame -> All]
```

and

```
GraphicsGrid[Partition[Table[Plot[x^i, {x, -2, 2}], {i, 1, 24}], 3], Spacings -> {3, 2}, Frame -> All]
```

---

**Edit:** I have managed to get the output working, but still need help on breaking the grid so that only three rows appear on one page.

```
myGrid = Grid[Partition[Table[Style[i, 24, "Times"], {i, 0, 80}], 4], Spacings -> {5, 5}, Frame -> All];
mynb = CreateDocument[{}, TextAlignment -> Center];    
Paste[myGrid];
NotebookWrite[mynb, Cell["", "PageBreak", PageBreakWithin -> True]];
Export["myGrid.pdf", mynb];
NotebookClose[mynb];
Clear[mynb];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`partition1` is the original data:

```
partition1 = Partition[Table[Style[i, 24, "Times"], {i, 0, 80}], 4];
```

Because `Length@partition1==20`, `UpTo` needs to be used to further `Partition` the data properly; then `Grid` is applied and finally it's `Riffle`d with a `PageBreakBelow`:

```
myGrid2 = Grid[#, Spacings -> {5, 5}, Frame -> All] & /@ Partition[partition1, UpTo@3, 3];
myGrid3 = Riffle[myGrid2, Cell["", "PageBreak", PageBreakBelow -> True]];
```

Then, with `Paste /@ myGrid3` instead of `Paste[myGrid3]`:

```
mynb = CreateDocument[{}, TextAlignment -> Center];
Paste /@ myGrid3;
NotebookWrite[mynb, Cell["", "PageBreak", PageBreakBelow -> True]];
Export["myGrid.pdf", mynb];
NotebookClose[mynb];
Clear[mynb];
```

yields

[image]