# Exporting a tall grid as pdf with reasonable pagination

Tags: export, pdf-format

I'd like a way of exporting a grid to PDF that isn't one super long page, moreover I'd like the page breaks to be chosen automatically (so that the grid fits/fills each normal sized page).

Is there some way to do this without having to tweak style-sheets or resort to printing?

**Example Code:**

```
Export["~/Downloads/tall_grid.pdf", 
    Grid[Partition[Table[
       Labeled[RandomImage[], ResourceFunction["RandomString"][10]], 
       {i, 200}], UpTo @ 5],
    Spacings -> {2, 2}],
    ImageResolution -> 600
]
```

**Related:**

- [Exporting a Grid over multiple pages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175177/exporting-a-grid-over-multiple-pages)
- [How can I export specific data into different pages in .PDF format?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17008/how-can-i-export-specific-data-into-different-pages-in-pdf-format)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, this is strange that such possibility is not a built-in function.

Let's say, we have a list of 150 strings like this:

```
tbl = Table[{a, ToString@(a RandomReal[{-2, 2}])}, {a, 1, 150}];
```

My workaround for pages formation is following:

```
spp = 64; (*the desired number of strings per page, depending on content size and page size*)

tmp = Table[
  tbl[[spp*i + 1 ;; spp*i + spp]], {i, 0, Length@tbl/spp - 1}];
data = Grid[#, Frame -> All] & /@ 
   Join[tmp, {tbl[[spp*Length@tmp + 1 ;; -1]]}];

cd = CreateDocument[
   ExpressionCell[#, PageBreakBelow -> True] & /@ data];
Export["file.pdf", cd]; NotebookClose[cd, Interactive -> False]
```

This makes the pdf-file with two full-length pages and one more partially filled..